# How can I write a Rails query to find phone number which are all saved with various formats

Tags: ruby-on-rails, postgresql, activerecord, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using Rails 5.2.0

I am trying to write a query to find a phone number based off user input. However, the format of phone numbers saved in the database varies (e.g. (123)-456-7890, +1(123)-456-7890, +1 123456789, and so on). Is there any way I can format the records saved in my database in this query? I've thought of adding a second column to the table that would simply be formatted_telephone, but I have tens of thousands of records. Can I add a method in the User controller to update these records when they are fetched?

Here is what I have so far:

```
User.where("REGEXP_REPLACE(telephone, '[^[:digit:]]', '') ~* ?", "%#{input}%")
```

Right now this is still only returning phone numbers with this format: 1234567890.

Am I on the right track with this? Or is it not possible to format columns when querying?

Comment: The best thing would be standardize the phone numbers to E164 format using something like phonelib, store both raw and standard formats if you want but use the standard format for calling/texting/querying/... Standardizing tens of thousands of records should only take a few seconds and certainly less time than trying to get a reliable version of your query.

Comment: (having been through this kind of problem myself) Users will enter phone numbers in a variety of formats, they should always be normalized to a digits-only format in the db. Then queries are straightforward and views can be consistently rendered. Rails has phone number view helpers to facilitate consistent presentation.

Answer (score 1):

Normally with a `where` clause and a regexp we are asking something like "find me everything that matches this regexp" but you are asking the DB for a phone number that matches "12035551212" and want the where clause to apply a regexp to every single phone number in the table while searching to match it. I guess you try something like (this can be streamlined but I'm breaking it down to make it easier to follow):

```
my_phone = '12035551212'

phone_arr = my_phone.split('') 
#=> ["1", "2", "0", "3", "5", "5", "5", "1", "2", "1", "2"]

regx = '^\D?' + phone_arr[0] + '?' + '\D*' + phone_arr[1..-1].join('\D*') + '$'
#=> '^\D?1?\D*2\D*0\D*3\D*5\D*5\D*5\D*1\D*2\D*1\D*2$'
```

now you have a regexp that matches only your phone number regardless of format. So now you can try:

```
User.where('phone_number ~* ?', regx)
```

this should ask Postgres to match your very specific regexp based on the phone number you are searching for. This should get you what you need. But I would look at refactoring it.

In the long run I would standardize all numbers in the DB. You could add a `phone_number_e164` column to Users and convert every one to the E164 format using a regexp. Then remove the old phone number column and rename the new one to `phone_number`. You would also need to add code to standardize any new numbers coming into the DB.

As a stop-gap measure you could also create a Postgres view that grabs the User records and applies regexp to the phone number to transform it to E164 format, and access that view instead of the User table.